# How to find the common bit pattern?

Tags: algorithm, assembly

I am writing a short program according to these requirements: `Write a program using bit flags that takes three different values and finds the bits they all have in common. Return the number that has all those bits in common.`
A `flag bit` is a name that you assign to a bit. For example,in `.equ KNOWS_MATHS, 0b1` the LSB is named KNOWS_MATHS.
Here is my code:

```
    .data
    .equ KNOWS_MATHS, 0b1
    .equ KNOWS_PHYSICS, 0b10
    .equ KNOWS_CHEMISTRY, 0b100
numbers:
    .quad 1, 3, 7 # 3 = 11b, 7 = 111b
results:
    .quad 0, 0, 0 
    
.text
.global main
main:
    movq %rsp, %rbp #for correct debugging
# check if first num knows maths
    leaq numbers, %rbx
    movq (%rbx), %rax
    andq $KNOWS_MATHS, %rax
    jnz knowsmaths
flag2:  
    movq (%rbx), %rax  
    andq $KNOWS_PHYSICS, %rax
    jnz knowsphysics
flag3:  
    movq (%rbx), %rax  
    andq $KNOWS_CHEMISTRY, %rax
    jnz knowschemistry
    
    jmp number02
knowsmaths:
    incq results
    jmp flag2
knowsphysics:
    incq results
    jmp flag3
knowschemistry:
    incq results
    
number02:
    leaq results, %rdx
    leaq numbers, %rbx
    movq 8(%rbx), %rax
    andq $KNOWS_MATHS, %rax
    jnz knowsmaths02
flag4:    
    movq 8(%rbx), %rax
    andq $KNOWS_PHYSICS, %rax
    jnz knowsphysics02
flag5:   
    movq 8(%rbx), %rax 
    andq $KNOWS_CHEMISTRY, %rax
    jnz knowschemistry02
    jmp number03
knowsmaths02:
    incq 8(%rdx)
    jmp flag4
knowsphysics02:
    incq 8(%rdx)
    jmp flag5
knowschemistry02:
    incq 8(%rdx)
    
number03:
    leaq results, %rdx
    leaq numbers, %rbx
    movq 16(%rbx), %rax
    andq $KNOWS_MATHS, %rax
    jnz knowsmaths03
flag6:    
    movq 16(%rbx), %rax
    andq $KNOWS_PHYSICS, %rax
    jnz knowsphysics03
flag7:   
    movq 16(%rbx), %rax 
    andq $KNOWS_CHEMISTRY, %rax
    jnz knowschemistry03
    jmp finish
knowsmaths03:
    incq 16(%rdx)
    jmp flag6
knowsphysics03:
    incq 16(%rdx)
    jmp flag7
knowschemistry03:
    incq 16(%rdx)
    
finish:

    movq $results, %rbx
    movq (%rbx), %r8
    movq 8(%rbx), %r9
    movq 16(%rbx), %r10
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

I am wondering if I should return `number 1` as it has the most common pattern or `number 7` because  it has the `most` bits. I must say I do not understand the requirements well as English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: "finds the bits they all have in common" sounds like they just want a three-operand bitwise and operation? Who gave you the requirement?

Comment: The way I read it, you should `and` the values together for the result, so e.g. if the inputs are `111`, `010`, `011`, the result should be `010`.

Comment: I am doing an exercise in chapter 9 from the book: learn to program in assembly by Jonathan Bartlett. In fact, I do not know what to do.

Comment: AND is bitwise intersection.  It's associative so it doesn't matter what order you AND together pairs of operands to end up with the same final value, the intersection of all 3.

Answer (score -2):

(I'm not used to AT&T syntax so if I make a typo please let me know)

Here's a method I like to use, that uses bit shifting. It's not optimized at all but that's just to show what's happening a little bit more easily. (If I were doing this for real I'd use a loop that terminates after you run out of bit flags.) Assume that `%rax` contains the bit flags of all the classes the student has taken.

```
andq $7, %rax     ;chop off everything but our three subjects of interest
leaq results, %rbx

shrq 1, %rax
jnc .next  ;if carry is clear, that bit was a zero so skip this one
incq (%rbx)

.next:
shrq 1, %rax
jnc .next2
incq 8(%rbx)

.next2:
shrq 1, %rax
jnc .next3
incq 16(%rbx)

.next3:
```

Comment: You're doing a 3-bit positional popcount.  The question wants an intersection (bitwise AND), and doesn't need the bits split across separate qwords of output.  The fact that the OP's code reserved more than 1 qword for output is a mistake.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The output having three qwords made me think it was looking for a list of classes taken. In that case a simple `andq 7, %rax` `cmpq 7, %rax` would do the job, no?

Comment: Maybe their full assignment has some other parts.  The part they describe in the text of their question is absolutely trivial, just one `mov` load and two `and` instructions.  I have no idea why they wrote so much code; maybe they just didn't understand the assignment either, or they're trying to intersect each bit separately instead of ANDing bit-masks.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use LEA to put an address into a register, use `lea results(%rip), %rdx`.  LEA with an absolute addressing mode is pointless and inefficient, and forces a 32-bit absolute address which can only work in a Linux non-PIE executable.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't work: you're shifting left by 1, but the low 3 bits are 61 bits away from being shifted out.  Either shift right, or start with `shl $62, %rax` instead of `and $7, %rax`.  (`and 7, %rax` is a load from absolute address `7`, but that's just a matter of AT&T syntax which you said you weren't sure about.)  Or better, use 32-bit `%eax` or 8-bit `%al` since you only have 3 bits.

Comment: Good to know. I'll be honest, I've only ever written 16-bit 8086 code, so I wasn't aware you could do that.

Comment: That was a typo, it was supposed to say `shr` instead.

Comment: I think Jonathan wants students to find an arbitrary bit pattern common to all three values, but I may be wrong, which is so difficult for beginners. (English plurality is confusing.)